# What is the T-SQL to normalize an existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to convert an existing table into the 1st normal form (simplest normalization possible; see the example).

Do you happen to know what is the T-SQL is for this sort of problem? Many thanks!

[image]

**Update**

Tried the answer below, it worked perfectly. Here is the steps I used to test the answer:

1. Start up Microsoft SQL Management Studio.
2. Create the tables, with the data below.
3. Make sure that the ID in "Customer" is set to "Primary Key", and "identity".
4. Make sure that the ID in "Order" has no special settings (its a foreign key).
5. Open up a database diagram, then create a 1:* relationship between the "Customer" and "Order" tables.
6. Execute the script on the "Customer" table and the "Order" table, it will automatically normalize the data properly for you.
7. This is very useful if you are starting from a flat .csv file that has just been imported, and you want to copy the information into a normalized form in the database.

Comment: Your image link is not working.

Comment: I agree that this is a sensible refactoring but it is not normalisation. There is nothing functionally dependant upon `name`.

Comment: I admit that this is a bit of a toy example to ask the question - the full problem is a bit more complex compared to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the Customer table

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Flat_CSV_File
```

If you have repeated imports

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name)
SELECT DISTINCT f.Name
FROM Flat_CSV_File f
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer c ON f.Name = c.Name
WHERE c.Id IS NULL
```

Orders (your table name Order is a reserved word in TSQL, so you need to quote it with square brackets)

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (CustomerId, Description, Cost)
SELECT c.Id, f.Description, f.Cost
FROM Flat_CSV_File f
INNER JOIN Customer c ON f.Name = c.Name
```

Comment: I wondered why brackets were used around [Order], thanks for clarifying why.

Answer (score 5):

In the case above @Thomas has a perfectly workable solution. However, sometimes people simplify for the sake of asking the question, so I'll address what you might want to do if you need to to go to many tables (or the first table has no unique constraint on name for instance), not just two.

First, I will insert the data to a staging table and add a column for the id which will be null. Then I would write an insert to the parent table using the OUTPUT clause to output the ids and the natural key to a table variable. Then I would use the table variable to update the id field in the staging table. Then I would insert records from the staging table to the other tables. Since I now have the id there, it is no longer necessary to access the orginal parent table. (If the number of records are large, I might also index the staging table).

Now if you have no natural key, the process becomes harder because you have no way to identify which record goes to who. Then I usually add an identity to the staging table and then do the intial import to the parent table one record at a time (including the stagingtableid as a variable in the cursor) and then update the staging table with each Parent table id as it is created. Once all the intial records are updated, I use set-based processes to insert or update to the other tables.

The staging table also gives you the chance to fix any bad data locally before trying to put it into your production tables.

Other syntax you may need to know if things are complex or if this is a repeated process is the MERGE statment. This will insert if it is a new record and update if it is an existing record.

If this is a very complex transformation, you may consider using SSIS.

Comment: SSIS = SQL Server Integration Services

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this will help to create a robust system design.

Comment: I wondered why I couldn't find SSIS, no matter where I looked. Thats because SSIS is not part of Visual Studio 2010 - I had to install Visual Studio 2008 to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to just write a query to do the import:

```
-- assuming that Id is an Identity column or has some default to generate keys.
Insert Customer( [Name] )
Select Name
From Flat_csv_file
Group By Name

Insert Order( [Customer], [Description], Cost )
Select C.Id, F.Description F.Cost
From Customer As C
    Join Flat_csv_file As F
        On F.Name = C.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off process, I would manipulate the .csv first, and form your tables there including the primary keys. When you populate the SQL database, use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers ON

INSERT Customers
(
   ...
)
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   openrowset(...)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Customers ON



SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON

INSERT Orders
(
   ...
)
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   openrowset(...)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON
```

If you need a purely TSQL solution, I would create temp tables to do the same basic thing, and insert from the temp tables instead of the .csv.

Comment: There is no reason to do a process where you turn identity insert on and off. This is not a good practice.